# Open read-only without getting message

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I have excel vba. As soon as I open excel file, the UserForm also opens without opening WorkBook. I can open Workbook with a button click but I want it to be read-only and not editable.

Now I have activated write protection under File -> Info -> write protection. Now when I open the excel file the message appears:

> "The author would prefer you to open 'file.xlsm' read-only - unless you need to make changes. Open read-only?"

That's not what I want. Is there a way to ignore the message or to automatically confirm with "yes" so that when someone opens the excel file, the message does not appear?

**Note:**
I dont want to use the code

```
Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=MyFile, ReadOnly:=True)
```

because i directly open UserForm when i open excel and workbook is not displayed, so i can't use this code.
if you want to know how I open a file, here is also my code on how to open UserForm without opening workbook.
Code in my ThisWorkBook:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    showLoginForm    
End Sub
```

Code for showLoginForm:

```
Sub showLoginForm()
    If isSheetVisible Then
        ' Only Hide this workbook and keep the other workbooks visible
        ThisWorkbook.Windows(1).Visible = False
    Else
        ' There is no other workbook visible, hide Excel
        Application.Visible = False
        ThisWorkbook.Windows(1).Visible = False
    End If
    UserForm5.show vbModeless
End Sub
```

Comment: Why can't you use `Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=MyFile, ReadOnly:=True)`? It doesn't prevent only your Userform showing or anything.. I just tested with the `ReadOnly:=True` and the userform showed as wanted without the workbook itself showing.